# Add grunt task to linemanjs application.js

Tags: gruntjs, linemanjs

I want to add a grunt task (specifically angular-template) to my lineman application.js file. There is some documentation found [here](http://linemanjs.com/) and [here](http://blog.testdouble.com/posts/2013-06-05-supporting-typescript-in-lineman.html). However, it just tells me to add the grunt task to `loadNpmTasks`. The problem is that from a fresh project created using lineman, my application.js file does not have a `loadNpmTasks` array, nor do the comments point out where I should put it.  Both examples I have found in the documentations do not show what the application.js file should look like in it's entirety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application.js file should look something like this (obviously the src/dest options are not configured correctly:

```
module.exports = function(lineman) {
  return {
    loadNpmTasks:['grunt-angular-templates'],

    ngtemplates:  {
        app:        {
            src: '**.html',
            dest: 'templates.js'
        }
    }
  };
};
```

Then to run the task:

```
lineman grunt ngtemplates
```